# Is it necessary to nil the object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, release

I have a view controller subclass of `UIWebView`. If I release that object is it necessary to nil the object?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will depend on how you use the pointer to the `UIWebView` subclass.  If this `release` is in `dealloc`, then you don't need to set it to `nil`, however if you `release` it elsewhere I would set it to `nil`.

Comment: It's in loadView then what will I do?

Comment: @ohmprakash As I said, I would set the pointer to `nil` if you are releasing it outside of `dealloc`.

Comment: But that app is crashes if i am not put the object to nil.

Comment: there might be strong references to the object and according to apple even an object with string association with other objects will get released only if other associated objects are released ,too.

Answer (score 0):

It's not binding to nil the object if you have already released it and if you are releasing means that you are not using ARC.Releasing the object simple means that its count is decreasing by 1 or zero in some case and still you can perform operation on it but the outcome would be nothing.(compiler doesn't give error message).

nil ensures that all the reference from that object to other objects are compensated or nil.(A good programming practice).

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not necessary. But it is a good practice to set the object to nil, because it remove the reference and messages to nil are ignored.